# EntryModel::populateModels throws a 500 error

Tags: plugin-development, error-message

I am retrieving a data set with about 5000 records and I am using the `EntryModel::populateModels($results)` to populate the model, this is causing a 500 error. When I limit the number of records returned to 100, it is working fine but when i set the limit to null it throws the error.

There isnt any error logged in the logs, and nor can it be a timeout because it only takes about 5 secs to return the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably an error in `craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` and there's a 99% chance the problem is you're hitting your `php.ini` file's [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) setting.

Populating 5,000 models is going to take a significant amount of memory.